# choose appropriate sampling frequency for yahoo data

Tags: signal-processing

let us consider following data from finance.yahoo.com

http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?a=&b=&c=&d=8&e=16&f=2014&g=d&s=MTLA.HM%2C+&ql=1

for MOTOROLA SOLTN (MTLA.HM), i want to analyse for example its spectra; structure ,identify if it contains some periodic components, identify significant frequencies and so on, but  for correct analysis  it is important to know its sampling frequencies , can i identify it  with this parameters

```
Daily
Weekly
Monthly
```

? thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are asking, but if you use a sampling frequency of $f_s$, then the sampled spectrum has a range of $[-f_s/2,+f_s/2)$. Thus, if you look at the spectrum using the daily data, it will have all frequency components corresponding to daily fluctuations and *slower* (i.e., weekly, monthly, yearly, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't comment (insufficient reputation) - so please accept this as a form of answer.

You don't say precisely what the purpose of the analysis is.   I am guessing, but it seems like you may be wanting to analyse stock movements to find patterns?   I think you want to be more specific in the question - at the moment it is very broad.

If I think about the question from a trading perspective.   People trade shares on the basis of a variety of sampling frequencies.   If your strategy is medium term (i.e. weeks to months) holding of shares then you are likely to be looking at daily or weekly movements.   Others may trade between days or even within the day (i.e. having a zero position overnight) - for those even daily data is too infrequent and they may be looking at data ever minute/few minutes.   These type of traders are generally trading off the data and market sentiment rather than company fundamentals.

I would presume there is a segment of traders who are looking at monthly data - those that are trading fundamentals of the company the share represents.

The other issue you have with lower frequency data is that the longer the time period a certain number of points represents - and therefore the data probably becomes more influenced by the general financial environment.

My view would be more frequent data (daily or better) and then take a peek at weekly and monthly.

Comment: thanks for reply, if i would take daily then what sampling frequency will be  good choice

Comment: purpose is spectral analysis

Comment: to show main   frequencies component

Comment: If you have daily data - i.e. like the Motorola dataset then the sampling has already been fixed in the dataset.   You will be limited by the dataset as to the highest frequencies you find in the data.

Comment: if it is fixed then how can i determine it?

Comment: does sampling frequency is equal to 1?

Comment: i would like to find  data that  can be analysed by fourier method

Comment: Any sampled data can be analysed, however the sampling frequency will determine the highest frequencies that can be found in the data.  If your data is sampled once a day you will not be able to find any frequencies higher than "per 2 days" (you need more than 2 samples per cycle).   I suggest that you do a search on "frequency aliasing".

Comment: in other word ,if i will take [pxx,f]=periodogram(mydata,[],[],samplingfrequency] what should i write for samplingfrequency?

Comment: @dato - this feels like we are moving increasingly away from a mathematics question.   I don't know how you are calling periodgram and I have not used it myself, but the sampling frequency of your data is per day, per week or per month.